# how to connect multiple app in Nodejs.... (Nodejs in action)

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

```
let api = connect()
        .use(users.users)
        .use(pets.pets)
        .use(errorHandler.errorHandler);

let app = connect()
            .use(hello.hello)
            .use('/api', api)
            .use(errorPage.errorPage)
            .listen(3000);
```

Source code in Nodejs in action..

It doesn't work. => 'api' is never called. Nothing happens when URL is /api.

How can I fix it?

**pets.js**

```
    module.exports.pets = function pets(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.match(/^\/pet\/(.+)/)) {
        foo();
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
}
```

**users.js**

```
let db = {
    users: [
        {name: 'tobi'},
        {name: 'loki'},
        {name: 'jane'}
    ]
};

module.exports.users = function users(req, res, next) {
    let match = req.url.match(/^\/user\/(.+)/);
    if(match) {
        let user;
        db.users.map(function(value){
            if(value.name == match[1])
                user = match[1];
        });
        if(user) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end(JSON.stringify(user));
        }
        else {
            let err = new Error('User not found');
            err.notFound = true;
            next(err);
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
};
```

and connect version is
"connect": "^3.6.6"

is it possible 'connect(app)'?

Comment: You'll have to provide us with a stack trace, any errors?

Comment: @MilanVelebit thanks for comment. if i run the server, 'api' is never working. api is never called.

Comment: Can you please show us the `users.users` and `pets.pets`?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed thanks for comment. i just edit it!

Comment: Looks like your regex does not match any path.

Comment: Try using a simple `if(req.url === '/pet')` to see if anything works.

Comment: `let app = connect()
            .use('/api', users.users)` if i use this code, it works!.
so i wanna know how can i 'connect' app! like this -> 'connect(api)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate **two** *connect* **servers**. What you want to do is chain those middlewares as 
`.use('/api', users.users);
 .use('/api', pets.pets);`

The first middleware will pass the request onto pets.pets via `next()`. 
You can read more at [this](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) link. Sadly connect doesn't support this type of chaining:

```
.use('/api', [users.users,pets.pets]);
```

Which would be a cute solution to your problem, but [express](https://expressjs.com/) supports it. 
So if you're looking into NodeJS, you should definitely get familiar with Express, Connect is a good starting tool but it's as simple as it gets without any decent functionality without some 'hacking' on your side.

Comment: Thanks! it's very helpful!!. it's really coool!
i'll press up button, as soon as i get 15 reputation. really thank you!

Comment: Glad you're excited, keep it up!

Comment: oh, if you don't mind, can you upvote my question?. if you do this, i can upvote your answer!